# Robust CNN Training

Tags: neural-network

I want to train a CNN on synthetically generated images that would resemble letters in real world photos with random backgrounds.

Is it better to train it on random backgrounds or just the letter shape (with a blank background)?

Is the network going to be indifferent to backgrounds if I only train on shapes?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your goal for the CNN. In general I would say the problem of background removal can be treated separately from letter recognition.

To that end it would be better to focus on the shapes themselves with various types of distortion applied.